# geom_hex() and stat_binhex() are not coloring tiles correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm not sure since when this doesn't work anymore, but the hexbinning in ggplot2 3.4.0 (`geom_hex()` or `stat_binhex()`) seems to mixup the color and tile coordinates?

The square-binning functions work fine, as evidenced by `stat_bin_2d()` working properly on the same data.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr) # for ggarrange

d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price))
ggarrange(d + geom_hex(), d + stat_bin_2d())
```

[image]

My session Info is the following, though I doubt it's specific to my machine since [the online documentation examples show the same striped patterns...](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_hex.html)

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggpubr_0.5.0  ggplot2_3.4.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] beeswarm_0.4.0    tidyselect_1.2.0  xfun_0.36         ica_1.0-3        
 [5] purrr_1.0.1       splines_4.1.2     lattice_0.20-45   carData_3.0-5    
 [9] colorspace_2.1-0  vctrs_0.5.2       generics_0.1.3    htmltools_0.5.4  
[13] viridisLite_0.4.1 yaml_2.3.7        mgcv_1.8-41       utf8_1.2.2       
[17] rlang_1.0.6       hexbin_1.28.2     pillar_1.8.1      glue_1.6.2       
[21] withr_2.5.0       pryr_0.1.6        lifecycle_1.0.3   stringr_1.5.0    
[25] munsell_0.5.0     ggsignif_0.6.4    gtable_0.3.1      codetools_0.2-18 
[29] evaluate_0.20     labeling_0.4.2    knitr_1.42        RAPToR_1.2.0     
[33] fastmap_1.1.0     parallel_4.1.2    fansi_1.0.4       Rcpp_1.0.10      
[37] broom_1.0.3       ROCR_1.0-11       scales_1.2.1      backports_1.4.1  
[41] limma_3.50.3      abind_1.4-5       farver_2.1.1      digest_0.6.31    
[45] stringi_1.7.12    rstatix_0.7.1     dplyr_1.1.0       rbibutils_2.2.13 
[49] grid_4.1.2        cowplot_1.1.1     Rdpack_2.4        cli_3.6.0        
[53] tools_4.1.2       magrittr_2.0.3    tibble_3.1.8      tidyr_1.3.0      
[57] car_3.1-1         pkgconfig_2.0.3   Matrix_1.5-3      data.table_1.14.6
[61] rmarkdown_2.20    rstudioapi_0.14   R6_2.5.1          nlme_3.1-161     
[65] compiler_4.1.2
```

Could anyone suggest a workaround?

Comment: This is a known bug in ggplot which has been fixed in the development version. See the linked duplicate for details and how to update ggplot.